# Are scheduled apex jobs allowed in Group and Professional Editions via ISV program

Tags: scheduled-apex, isv, group-edition, professional-edition

I'm building out a managed package via the ISV program which will run inside GE/PE.

I know that you can get APEX classes into GE/PE via the managed package, but can you schedule these apex classes? Ideally I need to create scheduled jobs in an ad-hoc manner dependant on the data inside salesforce.

You cannot schedule a job for an apex class through the GE/PE gui with the system adminstrator user as the apex classes don't appear (as managed apex classes are hidden).

You are however able create scheduled jobs programically through apex, so could you create a scheduled apex job via a trigger or the package install script for GE/PE?

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Mark, did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

From internal source -- I believe you can programmatically schedule the jobs. But not through the UI since the button doesn't show up (since GE/PE don't support Apex....but the package does).  Have you tried this using something like the Install Handler interface?

Comment: Thanks @ReidCarlberg I will attempt to schedule the apex job(s) through an apex trigger as the jobs will be ad-hoc and may need to happen more than once an hour.